# Open inline fancybox that captures parameter item from page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, gravity-forms-plugin

On my Wordpress website I have a list of regions on a page that each have a button opening the same form in a fancybox lightbox.

Using Gravity Forms I want to capture the region parameter (as seen below) by adding a variable that is a predetermined and truncated version of the section title, thus providing us with a better understanding of the button that was clicked.

The problem is Fancybox skips the parameter and opens the inline form, thereby bypassing the region parameter all together.

```
<a class="button" href="?region=<?php echo $region; ?>#contact-form" id="inline">Contact</a>
```

Is there a way to fix this without using ajax?

**Edit**
I've tried adding a callback to a function that adds the parameter to the URL after the lightbox opens, but i cannot get it to work any help here would be appreciated too...

```
$("#inline").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        addURL(this);
    }
});

function addURL(element) {
    $(element).attr('href', function() {
        return this.href + '&region=<?php echo $region; ?>';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I could not understand your issue.

You wrote:

> The problem is Fancybox skips the parameter and opens the inline form,
>   thereby bypassing the region parameter all together.

But you did not describe what is the expected outcome. I do not see any issue here, seems that the script does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: The expected outcome was an updated url 'http://example.com/?region=new-york#fancybox' but once fancybox is triggered the parameter is not added. I currently have the link open a form on a new page rather than a lightbox that seems to be a better solution anyway. Thanks though

Comment: In your example, the script will load element having ID "contact-form". So, your question and comment does not makes any sense to me. "The expected outcome was an updated url " - what url, where and why would you expect something to change?